# scrapy/xpaths/regex: proper xpath/re to ignore "link interjections"

Tags: regex, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping some korean language text and I come across a lot of "link interjection" for lack of a better word, where the html looks like this...

```
<a href="path" title="저">는</a> 좋아요
```

it shows '저' as a hyperlink but the '는 좋아요' as regular text. They are in reality part of the same word object and display on the page as '저는 좋아요요' but when scraping using this xpath and regex...

```
foo = response.xpath('//*[@id="divID"]/p//text()').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+')
```

it is broken into two words in a list...

```
foo == ['저', '는', '좋아요']
```

How can I get this to keep it as one word, as was my original intent?

```
intended: foo == ['좋는', '좋아요']
```

EDIT: (comment response)

the problem with .join() is that it will join all the regularly scraped words as well as far as I can tell. So I would end up with this...

```
''.join(foo) == ['좋는좋아요']
```

So I do not think that .join() will work unless there is something I am missing

Comment: is `''.join(foo)` helpful?

Comment: Break it up into two pieces of extraction: extract the text after the link ('좋아요') and extract the link-text itself. If you do this separately you can join '저' and '는' together.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to execute what you are suggesting, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work on the string representation of an HTML element, XPath has a [`string()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) that can be very helpful.

Once you have a single string for the element, you can apply regular expressions for words.

Here's a sample python interpreter session (I had to change your markup a bit to match the results you showed):

```
>>> import scrapy
>>>
>>> response = scrapy.Selector(text=u'<p><a href="path" title="저">저</a>는 좋아요</p>')
```

`.//text()` will select all descendant text nodes, as individual strings when `.extract()`ed (2 strings in this case):

```
>>> response.xpath('.//p//text()').extract()
[u'\uc800', u'\ub294 \uc88b\uc544\uc694']
```

And with the regex, you'll find 1 word, then 2 words:

```
>>> response.xpath('.//p//text()').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+')
[u'\uc800', u'\ub294', u'\uc88b\uc544\uc694']
>>> for e in response.xpath('.//p//text()').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+'):
...     print e
... 
저
는
좋아요
```

If you use XPath `string()` function on the paragraph element, you get a single string, even if the element has other children like `a`:

```
>>> response.xpath('string(.//p)').extract()
[u'\uc800\ub294 \uc88b\uc544\uc694']
>>> print response.xpath('string(.//p)').extract_first()
저는 좋아요
```

And you can then apply your regular expression to split on words:

```
>>> response.xpath('string(.//p)').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+')
[u'\uc800\ub294', u'\uc88b\uc544\uc694']
>>> for e in response.xpath('string(.//p)').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+'):
...     print e
... 
저는
좋아요
```

Note that `string(node-set)` only considers the first element in the node-set you pass as argument, so make sure your XPath expression first matches the element you want, or you can also chain XPath expression with scrapy selectors:

```
>>> for e in response.xpath('.//p').xpath('string(.)').re(ur'[\uac00-\ud7af]+'):
...     print e
... 
저는
좋아요
```